# Is there a native win32 client implementation of Apache Zookeeper?

Tags: visual-studio, apache, winapi, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to evaluate Apache Zookeeper (which looks really cool). Is there a win32 native implementation of the client?

Let me clarify native, I don't mean something that relies upon Cygwin, or port of some linux technology. I mean a 100% win32 implementation that I can build with Visual Studio (2005).

Cheers
Rich

Comment: So, the Java implementation of the client does not meet your needs? Are you not able to use the [C Client API](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ZooKeeper+C+client+API)?

Comment: No the java won't do. I have existing C++ code that I'd like to integrate the c api against. I can't use the C api because it doesn't build in Windows.

Comment: Possible solution: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-992

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have to say I don't really understand this, as these changes don't seem to be in the version I downloaded. Any ideas on how I get hold of these changes?

Comment: AHHHHH I understand, the win32 port has not yet been release. But I can take a version, however it may be unstable. Thanks for the link Justin.

Comment: The win32 port is already in use by at least one large company, so while it is new I wouldn't classify it as "unstable".